# React, Unable to make the row responsive using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a row which is a collection of columns, it displays properly in widescreen but has a problem in the mobile screen, I tried col-sm- but it didn't work. please help me solve this

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8UE.png)

Has you can see in the above image, all the elements in the same line
but when in switch to mobile the elements are divided into 2 rows [MobileView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ovvx.png). I want the row to adjust itself in a single line

My code

```
 <div className="row leaderBoard_main p-2 m-3">
                    <div className="col-1 leaderBoard_1">
                         <h4>1</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-1 leaderBoard_2">
                       <img className = "leadBoard_22" src="account.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8 leaderBoard_3">
                    <h4 className="">Username</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-2 leaderBoard_4">
                    <h4>10 Points</h4>
                     </div>
                </div>
```

CSS code

```
.leaderBoard_main {
  background-color:#0092FF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.leaderBoard_1 {
  color: white;
  border-right: 5px solid white;
}
.leaderBoard_2 {
  color: white;
}
.leaderBoard_22 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.leaderBoard_3 {
  color: white;
}

.leaderBoard_4 {
  color: white;
  border-left: 5px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the extra margin added by the row class. Try adding the "no-gutters" class to the row:

```
<div class="row no-gutters leaderBoard_main p-2 m-3">
</div>
```

To vertically center the text, add the classes d-flex and align-items-center to their containers, for instance:

```
<div class="col-1 leaderBoard_1 d-flex align-items-center">
  <h4>1</h4>
</div>
```

(Same for the divs with the classes leaderBoard_2 and 3)

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it, Can you please help me on why are the text not vertically centered?